# "Did you have the chance" or "Had you got the chance"?

Tags: verbs, verb-forms

My question is about this two sentences:
- "Did you have the chance"
- "Had you got the chance"

Both are correct? Is there any different meaning?

I read some article saying that in the first case the action can't be executed anymore, something like "you had the chance, lost it and now is impossible to make it". 
While in the second sentence the action still can be made: "you lost the chance, but you can do it yet".

Is is affirmation correct too??

Thanks for the attention!!

Answer (score 4):

Speakers of American English are more likely to say

> Did you have **a** chance to...? *OR*
>   Did you get **a** chance to...? *OR*
>   Have you had **a** chance to...? *OR*
>   Have you gotten **a** chance to...?

I cannot say whether this is also the case among speakers of British English, who would say the last as *Have you **got** a chance to...?*

All have the same significance: they all ask whether an opportunity occurred. Consequently,   answering in the negative does not mean that there was an opportunity but it was missed: it means that the opportunity was not there.